# Snap-to Drag and Drop event VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I am making a basic game in VB.Net, and I would like people to be able to drag and drop objects onto a 12 x 5 grid.

The issue I have is I'm not very experienced, and I would like a snap-to when the user drags and drops an object near a section of the grid.

My questions are:

What should I use to make a grid, or is a picturebox the best way of doing it?

How would I code the drop event to snap to a certain location on a 12 x 5 grid?

Thank you

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Yeah I don't really know how to put this into words. As you can tell I'm not an experienced programmer.